# How do we know which Hadoop Demons running on which node in a given cluster

Tags: hadoop

Let us assume I am new to a Hadoop cluster with multiple node which is already build, I want to know which demons are running on which node in this particular cluster is there any way?

Comment: Assuming that you want to do it programmatically, please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line 
hadoop dfsadmin -report  
will give you list of datanodes with basic statisics about them. It can be relatively easy parsed programmatically if you need. 
To get list of task trackers I would suggest to open web UI (port 50030) on your JobTracker. There is list of task trackers, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

We can use "jps" tool to know which daemons are running on the node. JPS stands for Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool.

jps will list all the java processes that are running in the system.